# How to make nginx use request port for try_files redirect?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have nginx listening on port 80 in a docker container which maps the port to 8080.

When I go to `http://example.com:8080/test` nginx redirects me to `http://example.com/test/` while I would expect it to be `http://example.com:8080/test/`.

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location /test {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /test.html;
  }
}
```

How do I make nginx use the request origin to make the redirect?

Answer (score 2):

Using `absolute_redirect off;` solved the problem.